# How to use latitude and longitude in Angular?

Tags: typescript, google-maps, angular16

I am trying to show a specific location in Google Map using Angular

in my html I have:

```
<google-map height="500px" width="100%" [center]="position" `[zoom]="zoom">`
    <map-marker [position]="position" ></map-marker>
  </google-map>
```

I have declared the type in property model as follows:

```
  lat: string;
  lng: string;
```

and in my JSON data file I have:

```
 "lat": "24.488354389767583",
 "lng": "54.39509929776173"
```

then in my TypeScript file I have the below code adding + sign to convert to a number:

the code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.form.controls['subject'].disable();
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.propertyId = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.route.data.subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.property = data['prp'];
      }
    )

    this.propid = this.propertyId;
    this.propidStr = "nums" + this.propid.toString()

       let data2:any = localStorage.getItem(this.propidStr);
       this.likes = JSON.parse(data2);
     
  }

  public zoom = 15;
    
    public position = {

      //use this.property. and create lat and lng
      
        lat: parseFloat(this.property.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(this.property.lng),
  
    };
```

but I am getting an error:

```
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value
```

Comment: I also tried parseFloat but also same result

Comment: You have `NaN` values.  Trace it back to see where  in your upstream you've accidentally lost the string or numeric value and converted it to NaN.

Comment: I have not done anything other than the code I put. Is it possible that it is not reading the variables from the model?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular (or Google Maps for that matter). Somewhere, you have a value in `this.property.lat` or `this.property.lng` that is not coercible to a number, and is therefore getting converted to `NaN`. You need to find where that is, but looking in your JSON and debugging to see what the value is that is not getting converted.

Comment: I added the html file that has the center attribute pointing to position. what is the issue with that?

Comment: Looking at the code again, it's probably because you're trying to eat the pizza before it's been delivered. You don't set `this.property` until `this.route.data` has emitted a value, but you're trying to get `this.property.lat` immediately.

Comment: I was not able to understand what i need to do? now in general how to set the center attribute in the html to include the lat and lng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went another approach by looking for location using company name.

```
this.dangerousUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps?q=" + this.property.theaddress + "&output=embed"
this.pdfSrc =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.dangerousUrl);
```